# How to convert nameless objects to JSON in java (using GSON)?

Tags: java, json, gson

I was writing a program to return JSON object using gson and I discovered something peculiar. Basically when I wanted to convert following object to JSON it gave me null.

```
Customer customer = new Customer() {
    {
        setId(1);
        setName("Foo bar");
        setAddress("Some Address");
    }
};
System.out.println(gson.toJson(customer));
```

where Customer looks like this

```
public class Customer{
    int id;
    String name;
    String address;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }   
}
```

but when I created object properly like

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setId(1);
customer.setName("Foo bar");
customer.setAddress("Some Address");
System.out.println(gson.toJson(customer));
```

it worked perfectly fine and gave output as supposed to.
Why does it matter how I create my objects. Is there difference between two methods?

Comment: Of course there's a difference. Make `Customer` final and your first approach won't work. Why? Because you're creating an anonymous instance of a subclass to `Customer`. That approach is called [double brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java) and has its drawbacks as Amongalen's link is highlighting. It you _really_ want to use code like this it might be better to create a builder and do something like `Customer customer = new CustomerBuilder().id(1).name("Foo bar").address("Some Address").build()`.

Comment: The difference is that the first one creates an anonymous class and then object of that class. In the second case you create an object of `Customer` class.

Comment: Btw. read this: [Don’t be “Clever”: The Double Curly Braces Anti Pattern](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the first case it is returning null because 'customer' object's class is an anonymous one which clazz.isAnonymousClass() return true

See below for GSon implementation

[image]